# UnsupportedOperationException When Adding Null to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, supercsv

I am trying to add null elements to an ArrayList.  This is for the purpose of ignoring columns using supercsv: http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_partial_reading.html  I am processing multiple csv files which have different number of header columns.

csvBeanReader.getHeader(true) returns String[].  The line headers.add(null); is throwing an UnsupportedOperationException.  Why?  What did I do wrong?

```
List<String> headers = Arrays.asList(csvBeanReader.getHeader(true));

//add null columns to headers
for(int i=0; i<1000; i++){
    headers.add(null);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have a `java.util.ArrayList`, you have something that implements `List`.  This particular `List` implementation doesn't support modification via changing the size of the `List`.  Even if you `add` an actual `String`, you will still get `UnsupportedOperationException`.  From [`Arrays.asList` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-):

> Returns a fixed-size list backed by the specified array.

To be able to add to that `List`, wrap it in an actual `ArrayList`.

```
List<String> headers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(csvBeanReader.getHeader(true)));
```

Comment: It looks like Collections.emptyList() is not a good choice as well - it does not let to add to the List too

Answer (score 0):

This is because `Arrays.asList` returns an immutable list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)

An immutable list will throw an exception when a modification is attempted.

Comment: The list isn't immutable; you can modify the elements.  It's just fixed-length, as wrapper around the array.